# JQuery Skipping click inside function

Tags: jquery

My problem is fairly simple: My code will start with an alert, and afterwards, should wait for the user to click a button in order to go on with the other alerts:  [(JSFiddle Here)](https://jsfiddle.net/3yc9chkm/3/)

```
function clicker(){
    alert ("Step 1.9: Clearly it is entering func");
    $("#button").click(function(){
         alert("Step 2 ALERT"); //SKIPS THIS PART
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("hello, step 1");

     if (1==1) {
          clicker();
          alert("Step 3:Done with 'if' ");
     }
     alert("step 4 DONE with whole code");
})
```

As you can see, the problem is that it keeps skipping alert #2. How should I write this code so that jQuery 'waits' for a click before moving on?

Thanks.

Comment: It is because you are just initializing the click event using  $("#button").click(....

Comment: Adding a click event does not pause the rest of the code until you click the button. If you do not want the rest of the logic to fire, than you need to put that logic inside of your click code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the 'clicking' function out of the clicker() function and put it in the if:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(1=1){
        ("#button").click(function(){
            clicker();
            //Rest of alerts HAVE to go in here
        })
    }
})
```

Sorry, but there is no other way to pause jQuery code.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Try using it like,

```
function clicker(){
    alert ("Step 1.9: Clearly it is entering func");
    $("#button").trigger("click");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
         alert("Step 2 ALERT");
     });
     if (1==1) {
          clicker();
          alert("Step 3:Done with 'if' ");
     }
     alert("step 4 DONE with whole code");
});
```

The problem with your code was that it was initializing the click event hence unless a click event for that id is not triggered it won't execute the code inside the event block.

Comment: so this code automatically 'clicks' the button for me? Any way to pause the code/ wait for user input instead?

Comment: yes it automatically triggers the click once you enter the clicker() function... You can remove the     $("#button").trigger("click"); section to allow user interaction.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page. If I remove the trigger part, the code will skip to step 3, thus not displaying step 2. Is there any way to stop the code to wait for the user to click the box and then continue with the rest of the code?